Nonvanishing of the discriminant modular form without product formula
Let $\Delta(z) := (E_4(z)^{3} - E_{6}(z)^{2}) / 1728 = \sum_{n \ge 1} \tau(n) q^n$ be the discriminant modular form, which is a weight 12 and level 1 cusp form. It is known that $\Delta(z)$ does not vanish for $z \in \mathcal{H}$ (complex upper half plane), and the only proof I know is using the product formula $\Delta(z) = q \prod_{n \ge 1} (1 - q^n)^{24}$ where $q = e^{2 \pi i z}$. I wonder if we can prove the nonvanishing result without referring to the product formula, but only using the definition above via Eisenstein series.
The question arose while I was reading W. Kohnen's paper "A Very Simple Proof of the $q$-Product Expansion of the $\Delta$-Function", which used the nonvanishing result in the proof.

Are you willing to use the fact that $\Delta(z)$ is related to the discriminant of the RHS of an elliptic curve in Weierstrass normal form?

Use the "valence formula" (see here for statement and proof), relating a sum over the zeros of a (nonzero) modular form to the weight of the form. It follows easily from this that since $\Delta$ vanishes at $\infty$, it can't vanish anywhere else.
